# Parse through data to align in columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PDF document that is poorly formatted. In general it is consistently in the same location. The point of the macro is to parse through the data and put each cell into the correct column. There are occasional amendments and I want to identify and move the data.

This is how the data looks when it is imported into Excel
[image: screen1]

This is how I want the output to look.
[image: screen2]

How do I parse through data correctly to align in columns?

Here is my Macro.

```
Option Explicit

' _
===================================================================== _
PUBLIC ENUMERATIONS _
=====================================================================
Public Enum eColumns
    [_first] = 0
    DocNo = 0
    Desc
    Issued
    CHKBOOK
    ACRN0
    Status0
    Issued0
    AcceptedDate0
    ACRN1
    Status1
    Issued1
    AcceptedDate1
    ACRN2
    Status2
    Issued2
    AcceptedDate2 = 15
    [_Last] = 15
End Enum


' _
===================================================================== _
SUBROUTINE: Main Sub Into Program _
=====================================================================
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   ----------------------------------------------------------- _
    Variable Declaration _
    -----------------------------------------------------------
'   Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

'   Range
    Dim rngRaw As Range
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngPaste As Range

'   ArrayList
    Dim alDataSet As ArrayList
    Dim alFormatted As ArrayList

'   String
    Dim strShtRawData
    Dim strShtFormatted
    Dim strDocText As String

'   ----------------------------------------------------------- _
    Object Initialization _
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    strDocText = "Doc No & Desc"
    strShtRawData = "Raw Imported Data"
    strShtFormatted = "Correctly Formatted"

    Set rngRaw = Sheets(strShtRawData).UsedRange
    r = rngRaw.Rows.Count
    Set rngPaste = Sheets(strShtFormatted).Range("A12")

    Set alDataSet = New ArrayList
    Set alFormatted = New ArrayList

'   ----------------------------------------------------------- _
    Routine _
    -----------------------------------------------------------
'   Loop through data and create ArrayList of "data breaks"
    For i = 1 To r
        If Trim(rngRaw.Cells(i, 1)) = strDocText Then
            alDataSet.Add i
        End If
    Next i

'   Create arraylist of arraylists (2D arraylist) for data
    For i = 0 To eColumns.[_Last] - 1
        alFormatted.Add New ArrayList
    Next i

'   Loop through data sets and fill empty arraylist with formatted data
    For i = 0 To alDataSet.Count - 1
        If i < alDataSet.Count - 1 Then

'           Set rngTemp equal to temporary subrange of entire raw range
            Set rngTemp = rngRaw.Offset(alDataSet(i) - 1).Resize(alDataSet(i + 1) - alDataSet(i))

'           Loop through subrange and put data into formatted arraylist
            For Each rng In rngTemp
                Select Case True
                    Case Trim(rng) = strDocText
                        alFormatted(eColumns.DocNo).Add rng.Offset(1).Value

                    Case Left(rng, 6) = "Random"
                        alFormatted(eColumns.Desc).Add rng.Value

                    Case Trim(rng) = "Issued"
                        alFormatted(eColumns.Issued).Add rng.Offset(1).Value
                        'TODO: Need logic to check if this is an ammended "Issued"
                    Case Trim(rng) = "CHKBOOK Obs"
                        alFormatted(eColumns.CHKBOOK).Add rng.Offset(1).Value
                    Case Trim(rng) = "ACRN"
                        'TODO: Add logic
                    Case Trim(rng) = "Status"
                        'TODO: Add logic
                    Case Trim(rng) = "ACRN"
                        'TODO: Add logic
                    Case Trim(rng) = "Accepted Date"
                        'TODO: Add logic

                End Select
            Next rng
        End If
    Next i

'   Once logic above is correct the arraylist will have enough columns _
    to not produce an error here. This "On Error" can be removed. For now, _
    it allows the script to run.
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'   Paste data from arraylist into range
    For i = 0 To alFormatted.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To alFormatted(eColumns.[_first]).Count - 1
            rngPaste.Offset(j, i).Value = alFormatted(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i

'   This can be removed when logic in select-case statement is finished
ErrorHandler:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```